# Why i am getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, in reversed() function?

Tags: python

i am trying to write a program to reverse words of string at there places.

**Example:-**

str = "my name is xyz"

will become

"ym eman si zyx"

following is the program:-

```
str = "my name is atharva"
l = str.split()
print(l)
for var in l:
    print(var)
    temp_str = list(reversed(var))
    print(temp_str)
    list = ''.join(temp_str)
    print(list)
```

**when i run the error i got the following error:-**

```
['my', 'name', 'is', 'atharva']
my
['y', 'm']
ym
name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Thanks in advanace.

Hope to here from you soon.

Comment: You are replacing the built-in object `list` by using a variable with the same name. Don't do that; rename your variable.

Comment: Convert into list then use builtin reverse function

Comment: Don't use `str` and `list` as names.

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of your loop, this line assigns a string to `list`:

```py
list = ''.join(temp_str)
```

On the next iteration you're trying to use `list` as the built-in function:

```py
list(reversed(var))
```

But the built-in can no longer be accessed, since you replaced it with your string.

Don't use existing names like `list` (or `str` for that matter) for your variables. This destroys your access to their existing functionality

Answer (score 1):

You are running over build in function [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)

`list = ''.join(temp_str)`

rename your var:

```
str = "my name is atharva"
l = str.split()
print(l)
for var in l:
    print(var)
    temp_str = list(reversed(var))
    print(temp_str)
    str_list= ''.join(temp_str)
    print(str_list)
```

*Also this is a bad practice running over build in function [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are using the `list` as variable name and assigning it a `str` value which shouldn't be the case. Just rename the variable `list` to some other name.
Also you can try out this code which is more optimized without using extra lists and all:

```
str = "my name is atharva"
l = str.split()
out = []
for var in l:
    out.append(var[::-1])
print (' '.join(out))
```

Output:

```
ym eman si avrahta
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to what I have provided below:

```
txt = "my name is atharva"
reversed_list = []
print(txt)
for var in txt.split():
    reversed_list.append(var[::-1]) #This reverses the text

print(' '.join(reversed_list))
```

The output will be:

```
my name is atharva
ym eman si avrahta
```

I have change certain variable names too.